How do mounted characters impact travel speed?
You travel speed in the strategic/world map is apparently based on the speed of the slowest character in the party. Suppose I have a party of 2 characters: Alice, a monk with speed 50, and Bob, a dwarf with speed 20. Bob mounts his trusty paladin steed, which has a speed of 50. Is the party's effective overland speed 20 or 50?
